# Displaying a data table followed by hiding the data table and displaying a div which has content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script that automatically paginates though an array of data displaying x number of lines per page.

After the last row of data has been displayed I need to run a jQuery function to display a Div for a set amount of time, then hide it and refresh the page. I currently have some code that checks the if there are any records relating to Signage. If any record are found run the following code:

```
var s = '<?php echo $totalRows_signage;?>';
console.log("T", s);
if ( s > 0  ) {
 $("#ConfData").hide();  // HIDE DATA TABLE
 $("#Signage").show();  // SHOW SIGNAGE DIV
 $(".container", window.top.document).hide() // HIDE PARENT 
 console.log("HIDE DATA ");
} else {
 $("#ConfData").show();  // SHOW DATA TABLE
 $("#Signage").hide();  // HIDE SIGNAGE DIV
 $(".container", window.top.document).show() / SHOW PARENT  
}
```

The issue with the above code is when the page loads it runs before the data table has been displayed. What I need is for the data table to display, roll through whatever number of pages there are, and then display the Signage Div, wait for x seconds and then refresh the page and start the process again.

How can I combine both the scripts together so it works as described.

- Step 1: load page and display data table
- Step 2: when the last row of data has been displayed, hide the data
  table and show the "div="#Signage"
- Step 3: display the "div="#Signage" for x amount of time
- Step 4: hide the "div="#Signage"
- Step 5: refresh the page.

  ```
   if($pageNo == $totalPages_conf) { 
   <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20;url=template20_1_L_iframe.php" /> --> REPLACE THIS WITH THE FUNCTION BELOW

   jQuery(function($j){
     $j('#Signage').show(0).delay(2000).hide(0); 
   })
   } else { ?>
   function refreshScreen()
   {
   try
   {
   if(window.external.getKioProperty('SVNRev'))
     return true;
   }
   catch(err){}
   return false;
   }
   function NaveXRefresh() {
   var URL = 'template20_1_L_iframe.php?pageNum_conf=<?php print $pageStrNo;?>&totalPages_conf=<? 
   print $totalPages_conf;?>';
   if (refreshScreen()) {
     window.external.Browser(2).parentWindow.location.href = URL;
   } else {
     window.location = URL;
   }
   return;
   }
   /// Replaces meta refresh
   window.setInterval("NaveXRefresh()", 9000) 
   }
  ```